# How to decrease margin programmatically on exported BIRT PDF reports?

Tags: birt

Is there a way to **decrease the margin** of the PDF reports using the **BIRT API**?

I tried setting the **PDF rendering options** to:

```
PDFRenderOption renderOption = new PDFRenderOption();
renderOption.setOutputFormat(PDFRenderOption.OUTPUT_FORMAT_PDF);
renderOption.setOption(IPDFRenderOption.PDF_HYPHENATION, true);
renderOption.setOption(IPDFRenderOption.PDF_TEXT_WRAPPING, true);
renderOption.setOption(IPDFRenderOption.PAGE_OVERFLOW,
                       IPDFRenderOption.ENLARGE_PAGE_SIZE);
```

Basically the problem I have is that if I have a longer text in a column (from one of the tables) it will get it on the next line, but if I set the `IPDFRenderOption.PDF_HYPHENATION` to `false` I will get the text split right in the middle of the text (see below).

### PDF with `IPDFRenderOption.PDF_HYPHENATION` set to `true`

[image: PDF_HYPHENATION is true]

### PDF with `IPDFRenderOption.PDF_HYPHENATION` set to `false`

[image: PDF_HYPHENATION is false]

So, I was trying to set the margin of the PDF to be smaller to overcome this issue, but I don't find any documentation on how to do this with the BIRT API...
There is [**this suggestion**](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/237757/) of modifying the master page, but I have way too many reports to modify them by hand.

How should I approach the problem? Is this even possible using the BIRT API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All I needed to do was to loop through all the handles, test which of them is a [**`MasterPageHandle`**](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.birt.doc.isv/model/api/org/eclipse/birt/report/model/api/MasterPageHandle.html) and call `setProperty` with these keys:

- `MasterPageHandle.BOTTOM_MARGIN_PROP`
- `MasterPageHandle.LEFT_MARGIN_PROP`
- `MasterPageHandle.RIGHT_MARGIN_PROP`
- `MasterPageHandle.TOP_MARGIN_PROP`

and the [**`DimensionValue`**](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.birt.doc.isv/model/api/org/eclipse/birt/report/model/api/metadata/DimensionValue.html) I needed.

### Code sample

```
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  private void shrinkPageSizeForExport(IReportRunnable reportRunnable) {
    DesignElementHandle designHandle = reportRunnable.getDesignHandle();
    IElementDefn elementDefn = designHandle.getDefn();
    for (int i = 0; i < elementDefn.getSlotCount(); i++) {
      SlotHandle slotHandle = designHandle.getSlot(i);
      for (DesignElementHandle elementHandle: (List<DesignElementHandle>)slotHandle.getContents()) {
        if (!(elementHandle instanceof MasterPageHandle)) continue;

        MasterPageHandle mph = (MasterPageHandle)elementHandle;
        DimensionValue dv = new DimensionValue(0.1, "cm");
        setAllMarginsTo(mph, dv);
      }
    }
  }

  private void setAllMarginsTo(MasterPageHandle mph, DimensionValue dv) {
    try {
      mph.setProperty(MasterPageHandle.BOTTOM_MARGIN_PROP, dv);
      mph.setProperty(MasterPageHandle.LEFT_MARGIN_PROP, dv);
      mph.setProperty(MasterPageHandle.RIGHT_MARGIN_PROP, dv);
      mph.setProperty(MasterPageHandle.TOP_MARGIN_PROP, dv);
    } catch (SemanticException se) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Cannot set margins for report export!", se);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternate suggestion:

Build a MasterPage in your BIRT library, and use it on all reports.  Then all reports it is used on can be updated at one time.  If you did not start with library MasterPages, you can replace the report MasterPage with the library master page, quicker then trying to recode them all.

Things like DataSources, and MasterPages are almost always better as library items.